# How an async call stack is implemented

Tags: function, compiler-construction, callstack

Say you have this function sequence (JavaScript)....

```
A(function(){
  console.log('done')
})

function A(done) {
  a()
  B(D, done)
}

function B(x, y) {
  x(function(){
    c()
    C(y)
    d()
  })
}

function C(z) {
  g()
  setTimeout(z, 1000)
}

function D(z) {
  h()
  setTimeout(z, 2000)
}

function a() {
  b()
  c()
}

function b() {
  // ... sync stuff
}

function c() {
  e()
  // ... sync stuff
  f()
}

function d() {
  // ... sync stuff
}
```

Tried making it so it has a sort of complicated call stack.

What I'm wondering is what the call stack looks like in different points in time. For example, the `c();C(y);d()` sequence. When `c()` gets called, the *next* function to be called at that level is `C()`. So it seems like it would push onto the stack (before evaluating `c()`), that `C()` is the return location. Then it goes to `e()` and `f()` (ignoring that for the moment). Then it checks the call stack and goes back to `C()`. Then same process. But since `C()` is async, it goes to `d()` before `C()` is complete. So it's like this:

```
c   c   c   c   c   c     c    ...?
    C   C   C   C   C    /  \
        e   e   f       C    d
            f
```

That's where my mind goes when trying to map out the call stack. It seems like it would form a tree. Now imagine multiple async processes starting all around the same time. Then it's like multiple branches to a tree. So instead of a call stack, a call tree. This makes me finally question how exactly the call stack gets evaluated. *When* the next function in the sequence is pushed onto the call stack, and *how* they update/remove the last finished function and find their way back to the next place in the call stack/tree.

Wondering if you could point out any resources that might describe this, or perhaps even explain how the call stack would look in the example I described above.

Comment: This really isn't an assembly question.  Don't think of it as a single call stack.  Think of async execution as multiple call stacks in threads.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a function, you push a return address on the stack, not the next function to be called.  The called function will then create its own frame on the stack (you can consider the return address part of that frame or separate from the frame, depending on how you look at it.  When the function returns, it will pop its frame and return to the return address (which will implicitly or explicitly pop the return address as well -- details depend on the CPU/VM architecture.

So for your example, the call stack over time looks more like

```
c c c c c C C
  e   f     g
```

Comment: But it seems the return address is the next function, I don't see how it's different. And also not sure what happens in the async case.

Comment: No, the return address is in the middle of the current function.  The next thing in the current function in this case is another call (to the next function), but it could be anything.